# How Can I Disable PastDates?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am Developing Sample Application in React-native. I am Using this Module to Calendar.

**Module Name is: react-native-calendar --save**

After that it's show and working fine this module both Ios & Android.

But How can I disable Past Dates.

Here this is my Code :

```
 <Calendar
                  ref="calendar"
                  showEventIndicators
                  //eventDates={['2017-03-19']}
                  events={this.state.value}
                  scrollEnabled
                  showControls
                  dayHeadings={customDayHeadings}
                  monthNames={customMonthNames}
                  pastDisabled
                  //selectedDate={'2017-03-19'}
                  titleFormat={'MMMM YYYY'}
                  prevButtonText={'Prev'}
                  nextButtonText={'Next'}
                  //onDateSelect={(date) => this.onDateSelect(date)}
                  onDateSelect={(date) => this.handleDateSelect(date)}
                  onTouchPrev={(e) => this.DatesFormat(e._d)}
                  onTouchNext={(e) => this.DatesFormat(e._d)}
                  onSwipePrev={(e) => this.DatesFormat(e._d)}
                  onSwipeNext={(e) => this.DatesFormat(e._d)}
                />
```

please Suggest me....

Is there any other Solution or Other Module please Suggest me......